# Argument of \cvdoubleitem has an extra }

Tags: errors, moderncv

I am trying to edit my resume that I had created in LaTeX.  It was working fine a few days ago, but now I am getting the error "Argument of `\cvdoubleitem` has an extra `}`" when I try to compile.  The block of code follows--the third line is the specific one that the error is popping up on.  But I can't figure out what the extra `}` is.

```
    \section{Computer skills}
    \cvdoubleitem{Solid Works}{}{Microsoft Word}
    \cvdoubleitem{ImageJ Analysis}{}{Microsoft Excel}
```

Comment: `\cvdoubleitem` takes *four* mandatory arguments and *one* optional argument (defaults to `.25em`). Here's the syntax: `\cvdoubleitem[spacing]{header1}{text1}{header2}{text2}`. So, perhaps you want `\cvdoubleitem{Solid Works}{}{Microsoft Word}{} \cvdoubleitem{ImageJ Analysis}{}{Microsoft Excel}{}`?

Comment: That worked, thanks!  I must have lost one of the {} sets in my copying and pasting of code.

Comment: I've converted my comment into an answer.

Answer (score 1):

`\cvdoubleitem` takes *four* mandatory arguments and *one* optional argument (defaults to `.25em`). Here's the syntax:

```
\cvdoubleitem[spacing]{header1}{text1}{header2}{text2}
```

So, perhaps you want

```
\cvdoubleitem{Solid Works}{}{Microsoft Word}{}
\cvdoubleitem{ImageJ Analysis}{}{Microsoft Excel}{}
```